# Virus Infection; Now I'm trying to delete folders from Program Files

Tags: windows-7, malware

AVG seems to have quarantined the two Trojan malware but I can't delete the folders:

Program Files > Google > Desktop > Install > {string of numbers}

Changing **Ownership** and **Permissions** doesn't do anything except get Windows Explorer rebooting.  Or, there's a pop-up message saying access is denied.

There's a Lock icon on the top, Google, folder.

Has anyone found a way to delete a rooted-in folder in Program Files?

Thanks

Update: The advice was overwhelming to reinstall the OS, so I did that.  I backed-up only file formats that were safe, like .odt, .jpg, .avi or .mpg.  Those went to a different hard drive and I ran two checks of those files with AVG.
Then I performed a clean install which first formatted the infected drive.
So far so good, and thanks, everyone, for taking the time to lend advice.

P.S.
I was certain this wasn't a duplicate question because I searched for other references to that string of folders: Google > Desktop > Install...   Search didn't reveal any references to it.  So I asked how to remove that Folder and its contents.
I may have received a duplicate solution to the problem -- format and start over -- but I didn't see a duplicate of my question.

Comment: what message do you get when you try to delete the file?

Comment: A program called Unlocker is very helpful

Comment: See here http://superuser.com/a/511024/165442 and here http://superuser.com/a/512901/165442

Comment: Just as some advice, I (and most seasoned computer techs) would recommend re-installing the operating system. Even if you get any side-effects from the virus to go away, it may only be temporary. Re-installing the operating system is the only sure way to remove a virus from your computer. You should have backups of your important files, so you can just revert back to those, unless they are infected.

Comment: To  druciferre:The error message pop-up says "Error Applying Security [line] An error occurred while applying security information to [line] C:Program Files/Google... [line] Access denied"

Comment: to That Brazilian Guy: I'd hoped to find someone familiar with the specific locked Folders I've got, but the main message here from everyone is 'nuke it from orbit to be sure'.  I guess I'll just do that.

Comment: Just to check: Would it be safe to backup .doc and .odt files, game backups, .jpg and other image files, or has something in recent times changed concerning the safety of those file formats?  I'd backup those and then format the drive and start over.

Comment: (How do I mark this message "Solved"?)

Comment: I have written an answer, you can choose it as accepted, or you can write your own answer and accept it (24 hours later). Or you can leave it as it is if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In malware infections, [the overwhelming consensus](https://superuser.com/a/511024/165442) is to erase everything and [do a clean reinstall of the operating system](https://superuser.com/a/512901/165442).

You should always perform backups periodically, so in case of an infection you can count on your safe backed-up data. If that is not your case, you can't assume your files are safe, `.doc` files can contain macro viruses and [even media files can contain malware](https://superuser.com/a/445381/165442).

In case you don't have a backup for some important file, and it's impossible to re-download it from the original source, you should copy it to an external drive, then [use Virus Total to scan the file using 40+ different antivirus engines](https://www.virustotal.com/), then use a [linux Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) to copy it back to your newly-installed OS, because even the external drive could have been compromised when you backed up the files.