# Would it be possible for a running virus or malware to hide or pause when the task manager is running in windows 10?

Tags: windows, virus, malware, task-manager

I found that my computer running slowly, but, when the task manager is running, the computer would become more smoothly.

Does this mean my computer is running malware or virus?

Would it be possible for a running virus or malware to hide or pause when the task manager is running in windows 10?

If so, how could we find out which is the host process of the malware or virus?

We can never know all the processes in task manager to be secure. Viruses often use names of system components for a reason, sometimes even displacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Running processes can see other processes and know when they are running.

The proof of this is that you do not need administrator rights to run Task Manager. Anything Task Manager can do, another program can do as well.

Our advice on malware is already contained in other questions

- [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)
- [How can I fix a computer that is infested with malware and is extremely unresponsive?](https://superuser.com/questions/511019/how-can-i-fix-a-computer-that-is-infested-with-malware-and-is-extremely-unrespon)